# How to keep a window in front of another applications window

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I needed to display flashing border in on top of chosen application's window (in my example the application is cmd.exe). I used layered windows for this purpose. Everything works fine, except the one thing: I can't bring target window (in my case - cmd.exe) in front if it is overlapped by another window (if another window is in the foreground). It works when I maximize/minimize target window, but doesn't work in case when target windows is overlapped. I can't restore in clicking on app's icon in the taskbar.

```
const COLORREF MY_COLOR_KEY = RGB(255, 128, 0);
HWND cmdHanlde = NULL;
constexpr unsigned int timerIdWindowUpdate = 1;
constexpr unsigned int timerIdFrameColor = 2;
bool tick = false;
bool minimized = false;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
             _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
             _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
             _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MyTransparentFrame";
    wc.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;

    wc.lpfnWndProc = [](HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps{};
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            RECT rc{}; GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
            HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 5, tick ? RGB(255, 128, 1) : RGB(255, 201, 14));
            HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(MY_COLOR_KEY);
            HGDIOBJ hOldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
            HGDIOBJ hOldBrush = SelectObject(hdc, hBrush);

            Rectangle(hdc, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);

            if (hOldPen)
                SelectObject(hdc, hOldPen);
            if (hOldBrush)
                SelectObject(hdc, hOldBrush);
            if (hPen)
                DeleteObject(hPen);
            if (hBrush)
                DeleteObject(hBrush);

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            if (wp == timerIdWindowUpdate)
            {
                WINDOWPLACEMENT windowPlacement = { sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT), };
                if (::GetWindowPlacement(cmdHanlde, &windowPlacement))
                {
                    if (windowPlacement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
                        || !IsWindowVisible(cmdHanlde))
                    {
                        minimized = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RECT rect = {};
                        DwmGetWindowAttribute(cmdHanlde, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &rect, sizeof(rect));
                        MONITORINFO monInfo;
                        monInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
                        GetMonitorInfoW(MonitorFromWindow(cmdHanlde, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST), &monInfo);
                        if (cmdHanlde != NULL && ::IsZoomed(cmdHanlde))
                        {
                            rect.left = monInfo.rcWork.left;
                            rect.top = monInfo.rcWork.top;
                            rect.bottom = monInfo.rcWork.bottom > rect.bottom ? rect.bottom : monInfo.rcWork.bottom;
                            rect.right = monInfo.rcWork.right > rect.right ? rect.right : monInfo.rcWork.right;
                        }
                        if (minimized)
                        {
                            ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, cmdHanlde, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
                            minimized = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ::SetWindowPos(cmdHanlde, hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
                            ::SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top,
                        SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (wp == timerIdFrameColor)
            {
                tick = !tick;
                ::RedrawWindow(hwnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
            }
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
        }

        return 0;
    };

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE |     WS_EX_LAYERED |     WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, wc.lpszClassName, L"", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED,
0, 0, 0, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    ::SetTimer(hwnd, timerIdWindowUpdate, 50, NULL);
    ::SetTimer(hwnd, timerIdFrameColor, 500, NULL);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, MY_COLOR_KEY, 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    cmdHanlde = FindWindow(L"ConsoleWindowClass", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

So the question here is how to restore target window after it was overlapped by another window?

Comment: I think this should be stripped down to a minimal example. All the layered window and custom draw code is not really relevant to the question. It should be just a plain window.

Comment: The weired behaviour is because of `::SetWindowPos(hwnd, cmdHanlde, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);` and `::SetWindowPos(cmdHanlde, hwnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);`

Comment: @Swordfish, could you please explain what is weird here and how it should be?

Comment: @rudolfninja I referred to not being able to restore the minimized `cmd.com` with one click. It needs a couple of clicks and luck to get it restored.

Comment: @Swordfish, Yeah, but I'd like to restore it from the first click. Is there a way to it?

Comment: If you make your window owned by the target window you get the "on top" behavior for free.

Comment: @JonathanPotter But then you are attaching input queues, of which Raymond Chen [warns](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683/) all over in [his blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143).

Comment: @zett42 agreed although if all the OP is doing is displaying a flashing border (as he says) then there's no input involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (minimized) {
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
    minimized = false;
} else {
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, 
                 rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, GetNextWindow(cmdHandle, GW_HWNDPREV), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
}
```

Comment: I think the two `SetWindowPos` calls could be reduced to one.

Comment: Just did a quick test - seems the separate calls are required, as the system ignores the position/size, if z-order is also specified.