# make WPF window on top of an external app window, but not topmost of every window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi

I need to extend an external Windows application with a fake toolbar. I can't modify that external application at all.

My fake toolbar app is an WPF app, with WPF MainWindow, C#.

This toolbar should appear on top of external app window, but not as system wide topmost.

I can get external app window HWND, size, rect and so with proper Win32 API functions or with WindowInteropHelper.

I may be able to hide my app window if it is not 100% visible by `WindowFromPoint`  Win32 API call, but this is not the best idea.

Any idea how I should solve this?

I tried with `SetWindowPos` WIN32 API fuction but no success.

`SetWindowPos(myapp_hwnd, externalapp_hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0002);`

---

**EDIT:**

Solution I found is to call `SetWindowPos` twice as mentioned here:
[How to keep a window in front of another applications window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918333/how-to-keep-a-window-in-front-of-another-applications-window/52920807#52920807)

```
SetWindowPos(myapp_hwnd, 0, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER);

SetWindowPos(myapp_hwnd, GetNextWindow(extapp_hwnd, GW_HWNDPREV), 0, 0, 0, 0, 
             SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: at this moment my best idea is to see if  my app window 4 corners are visible by ```WindowFromPoint``` and hide my app window if it is not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52920807/7571258

Comment: Hi zett42, thanks for your help, that's what I need. I need to call SetWindowPos twice to get the correct result.

Comment: The way to make one window always be above another in the zorder is to use window ownership

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Not a good idea when the windows belong to two different processes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130607-00/?p=4143), as in OPs case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep a window in front of another applications window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918333/how-to-keep-a-window-in-front-of-another-applications-window)